# what is class refers to in python gae?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have seen this in one the facebook.py User file.

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required=True)
@classmethod
def get_by_email(cls, email):
    return cls.query(cls.email == email).get()
```

What does cls mean? if you put self, it is referring to the User class normally. But what's cls refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question. It has a great answer with a little tutorial about the magic of wrappers, closures and decorators : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: This is not a GAE question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name does not matter, but applying `classmethod` decorator makes the method a class method. In such case the first argument is a class, not an instance.

Please take a look at the comparison of instance, class and static methods using the following code:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    def instance_method(sth, x):
        return sth, x
    @classmethod
    def class_method(sth, x):
        return sth, x
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(x):
        return x


>>> a = Test()
>>> a.instance_method('abc')
(<__main__.Test object at 0x0000000002C26D30>, 'abc')
>>> a.class_method('abc')
(<class '__main__.Test'>, 'abc')
>>> a.static_method('abc')
'abc'
```

By convention, when you are referring to the same instance, you name it `self`. When you are referring to its class, you name it `cls`. That is only a convention, but it is better to follow it for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

"cls" is a conventional identifier used to mean "class".

The @classmethod decorator makes a call to the method, ex. `obj.method(arg)`, pass to the first parameter (cls in this case) a class object representing the class of the object.

Without the @classmethod decorator, the object itself would be passed to the first parameter (cls in this case).